# Как запустить метод внутри другого метода?

Tags: jquery, javascript

```
var user = functopn(usName){
 this.name = usName;

 // метод установки имени
 this.setName =function(newName){
  this.name = newName;
 }

 // 2-й метод, задает новое имя Tolbase
 this.newName = function(){
  this.setName('Tolbase');
 }
}
```

2-й метод является ошибочным. Так все же как правильно вызвать метод внутри другого метода?

Comment: Почему ошибочным?

    var u = new user('lol');
    alert(u.name);
    u.newName();
    alert(u.name);

Отрабатывает как должно.

Comment: Да! Дей-но! Я понял почему несрабатывает у меня, но не знаю что с этим делать, если метод препдолагает такую конструкцию: this.newNmae = function(){ setInterval(function(){ this.setName('Tolbase'); },1000); }, понимаете о чем я?

Comment: Понимаю и вам верно ответили)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Забыли `new` еще. иначе `user` останется функцией, а не станет объектом, как следствие `user.setName` будет `undefined`.

```
var user = new function(usName){
  this.name = usName;
  var _user = this;
  // метод установки имени
  this.setName =function(newName){
    _user.name = newName;
  }
}
```